# Can I check which database is running configuration and content for a WSS 3.0 site?

Tags: sql, sharepoint, wss

The problem is I have full access to the server where the Sharepoint site is hosted etc, however all i've ever done is maintained the site. I didn't set it up.

There is now an issue where Sharepoint can't connect to the Config or Content databases. I don't know which of our servers run these, so is there anyway I can find out, maybe from a config file or anything which server/database I need to check.

Other websites on the web server are still running fine, I know the database isn't on that same server because i've checked.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is central admin website running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Event Viewer Log. There would be an entry similar like this:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source: Windows SharePoint Services 3
Event Category: Database 
Event ID: 3760
Date:  4/16/2009
Time:  11:51:07 AM
User:  N/A
Computer: IMIAPP03
Description:
SQL database  **'STS_Config'** on SQL Server instance 'np:\\.\pipe\MSSQL$Microsoft##SSEE\sql\query' not found. Additional error  information from SQL Server is included below.

Cannot open database "STS_Config" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Comment: This wasn't the exact error but I just looked in the error log for a database that was constantly throwing errors.

Answer (score 1):

I normally find the easiest way is to look at the site collections settings in Central Administration (which you should be able to access if you have root access to the server WSS 3.0 runs on)

Take the following steps once in the Central Administration site:

- Go into Application Management
- Go into Content Databases
- Select your web application using the selector which is orange in the top right of the main content of the page
- Click the name of the database displayed

Once you are at the final point you should see at the top information for **Database Server** and **SQL Server Database Name**.  Hopefully this should point you in the right direction of where your database is being stored.

If your access to the database content database is cut due to incorrect login details to the SQL server (i.e. the SA account's password has changed), the SQL credentials can be updated here too for the selected content database.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this would not work when there is a problem connecting to the database. It does however work when the site is functioning properly +1